# Need help in mongodb $pull

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb document that is like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5231718f042f8bc215000007"),
    "ApplicationId": "YVo9bEQiDLg2",
    "Network": {
        "Millennial Media": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 352,
            "App": [
                {
                    "AppId": "APID - Banner",
                    "AppValue": "76970",
                    "Priority": 100
                }
            ]
        },
        "Buzzcity": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 353,
            "App": [
                {
                    "AppId": "Partner ID",
                    "AppValue": "80624",
                    "Priority": 100
                }
            ]
        },
        "Adiquity": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 354,
            "App": [
                {
                    "AppId": "package",
                    "AppValue": "com.ristomobile.giftntake",
                    "Priority": 0
                },
                {
                    "AppId": "Site ID",
                    "AppValue": "adqkkqkk-14eo91zj-qv6qt",
                    "Priority": 100
                },
                {
                    "AppId": "appName",
                    "AppValue": "Gift&Take",
                    "Priority": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        "Smaato": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 351,
            "App": [
                {
                    "AppId": "Adspace ID",
                    "AppValue": "65766605",
                    "Priority": 100
                }
            ],
            "Partner": [
                {
                    "PartnerId": "Publisher ID",
                    "PartnerValue": "923862008"
                }
            ]
        },
        "AdNear": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 367,
            "Partner": [
                {
                    "PartnerId": "pubid",
                    "PartnerValue": "rs-1328"
                },
                {
                    "PartnerId": "api_key",
                    "PartnerValue": "RSW78:QH8HHM389M7YP"
                }
            ]
        },
        "twinpine": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 371,
            "Partner": [
                {
                    "PartnerId": "pid",
                    "PartnerValue": "1551a74d1df075a"
                },
                {
                    "PartnerId": "alid",
                    "PartnerValue": "405"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Vserv.mobi": {
            "Active": true,
            "RefreshInterval": 300000,
            "NetworkId": 370,
            "Partner": [
                {
                    "PartnerId": "Zone Id",
                    "PartnerValue": "32024"
                },
                {
                    "PartnerId": "Publisher Id",
                    "PartnerValue": "12649"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "LastUpdate": ISODate("2013-06-24T01:44:22.865Z")
}
```

and i tried to pull away the Millenial Media data:

```
db.MediationSetup.update(
{
    ApplicationId: "YVo9bEQiDLg2"
},
{
    $pull: {
        Network: {
            "Millennial Media": {
                "Active": true,
                "RefreshInterval": 300000,
                "NetworkId": 352,
                "App": [
                    {
                        "AppId": "APID - Banner",
                        "AppValue": "76970",
                        "Priority": 100
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

but it gives

> Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array

I am puzzled, I am indeed pulling an array! so what is going on?

Comment: can you please format your document- and code-example properly? Usually I would do this myself, but I get dizzy just by looking at it. You can use `db.collection.find(...).pretty()` in the Mongo shell to auto-format the returned documents.

Comment: `Network` is an object, not an array, so you can't use `$pull` on it.

Comment: @Philipp, for formatting json documents I use json lint (this one for example: http://jsonlint.com/). When I put document there and press Validate it formats it.

Answer (score 0):

When I understood you correctly, you want to remove an entry from the array in Network.Millennial Media.App.  In that case you have to reference a field nested in sub-documents by using the [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation):

```
db.MediationSetup.update(
{
    ApplicationId: "YVo9bEQiDLg2"
},
{
    $pull: { "Network.Millennial Media.App": {
                        "AppId": "APID - Banner",
                        "AppValue": "76970",
                        "Priority": 100
              }
   }
});
```